# Machine Learning algorithm where variable importance depends on the value of other variables

Tags: machine-learning, modeling

I am designing an algorithm that can detect cheating in a game of chess.

I have a database of players who have been flagged by moderators as cheating, along with a number of game-level characteristics such as move times and move accuracy (as determined by a chess engine) for both black and white.

Let's specify a simple regression:

`cheatflag ~ whiteMoveTime + blackMoveTime + whiteMoveAccuracy + blackMoveAccuracy`

Let's say cheatflag is a factor-level variable that is 0 if no cheater, 1 if white is the cheater, 2 if black is the cheater.

The issue is that the predictive value of variables like whiteMoveTime and whiteMoveAccuracy depends crucially on who is doing the cheating. If white is cheating, those variables should have different coefficients than if black is doing the cheating. As far as I know, running most blackbox algorithms will derive coefficients that average across all the cases of cheating without understanding the hierarchical nature of the variables.

This problem has a Bayesian flavor with some kind of conditional assumption -- if black is cheating, then these variables matter; if white is cheating, these variables matter, and so on.

I know I could run two separate machine learning models, one for white cheaters and one for black cheaters, but I feel that that throws out very useful information that a single ML model would be able to capture.

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: The difficulty here may be related to... what if they are *both* cheating?

Comment: You could run it twice, once from the perspective of white, once for black. (And you would need to find out if the stats of the respectively other color are interesting or not) I hope you mean logistic regression and not linear regression. There are other issues as well regarding how to aggregate from single moves to the entire game. You could flag the player as cheating as soon as one move is flagged, but honestly, single great and quick moves happen

Comment: Thanks for both of your feedback.  To be clear: I know in advance what players were cheating (flagged by human moderators).  The goal is to generate an algorithm that can predict human-level classification.  I have lots of variables to play around with (move times, move quality, and so on), but that is not relevant.  What is relevant is the structure of the algorithm: the algorithm needs to be sensitive to a hierarchical nature of the task.  The accuracy of black's move times matter A LOT more if black is the cheater, and nearly not at all if white is the cheater.

Comment: As such, averaging across the games gets the wrong coefficients for each variable.  As mentioned, David, I could run two separate logistic regressions, one for black_cheater = 1 and one for white_cheater = 1, but you lose information that way, and it's computationally more expensive than running a single comprehensive model on the whole dataset.

And both players cheating is an interesting problem, but it's non-existent in the dataset, so not an objection I need to deal with now.  In any case, it can be detected by running the two separate models as explained above.

Comment: I think you're looking at this from the wrong perspective: you should be worried about *players' patterns of behavior across games,* not modeling the opposing sides in any particular game.

Comment: In this dataset, however, we have no unique player identifier. We are looking at one-off games, and are told they either cheated or did not cheat.